# How to stop Silverlight upgrading between point release automatically

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight application. The application was compiled with version 4.0.x. Today the application has told me that we need to upgrade to a newer version of 4.0. We don’t want to upgrade to the newer version as we will need to do it on all our client machines. Is there any way we can get our application to use the older version of Silvlight instead of asking for the upgrade. We compiled with the old version and are happy to use that.

**Edit**

It looks the update has gone from 4 GDR 1 4.0.50524.0 2010-06-03  to 4 GDR 2 4.0.50917.0 2010-09-28 ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight#Release_history))

Answer (score 0):

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/28/keeping-your-silverlight-dev-environment-stable-through-service-releases.aspx seems to answer my question.

- Keep up-to-date on the latest developer runtime
- Have the RTW SDK installed